# How to debug a Linux I2S audio input issue

Tags: linux, debugging, raspberry-pi, alsa, dma

I am trying, and failing, to connect an I2S microphone (Invensense ICS43432) to my Raspberry Pi (B+) running Arch Linux.  I have asked for specific advice in the relevant Arch Linux ARM forum but my question is really more general than that: how does one go about debugging Linux audio *input* issues?

I have verified with a logic analyser that the I2S microphone is sending sensible data in the correct channel (left) and the correct pin of the Raspberry Pi.  The I2S microphone appears under ALSA as a "sound card".  `arecord` is perfectly happy to record from that device and I have boosted the gain of that device using `alsamixer` by 30 dB.  Yet all the data bytes of the recorded file are zero.

How does one go about checking the flow of audio data, the operation of DMA, under Linux?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](http://iot.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Not sure I follow: is the process of debugging not a part of programming and development?  The very name "StackOverflow" suggests that it is.  This is intended to be a methodology question, not a "debug this thing for me" question.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem trying to record in stereo, using 2 Adafruit I2S MEMS breakout mics: arecord worked fine, but zeros when using ALSA to write to a bin file. Choosing a 32 bit word format (Little Endian 32 bits, Signed) made it work. Only I end up with 64 bit stereo Frames.